# What's the recommended method of circumventing infinite recursion with the scene_update_post handler?

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a Blender addon that stores extra information inside a mesh (as custom vertex data layers).
The information in these extra layers needs to be recalculated whenever the mesh changes. More specifically, this custom data is a function of the vertex position, so whenever a vertex's position changes, the data needs to be recalculated.

One way to recalculate the data when vertex positions change (the only one I know of) is by handling
`bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post`. However, when I write the recalculated data to the mesh, `bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post` is triggered again (as it should be)! This leads to an infinite recursion.

This behavior of `bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post` is intentional. A similar thing happens with `update` callbacks for custom properties, as documented [on developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/T27793).

> What is the recommended way of sidestepping this problem? In other words, how can I avoid infinite recursion when handling `bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post`?

Comment: You can store everything in custom dictionary using vertex ids as keys which does not trigger scene update. Depends what you need to do with that data and how fast and when you need to access it. Generally I am strongly against anything python related that needs to be updated on every mesh update operation. This makes Blender extremely slow. Slower than it already is.

Comment: i would suggest a global bool variable : the function run and set it to False he next time it won't run and set to True and this will break the loop ( scene_update_post-->my_func-->scene_update_post)

Comment: @Chebhou - Thanks for the suggestion! Would you consider making it into an answer? I considered this earlier, but I see two possible complications. First, if my handler makes multiple edits to the scene, it causes multiple invocations of itself. This can be taken care of by carefully counting how many calls are made that update the scene (a headache, and you'd have to figure out exactly which calls update the scene, but possible). Second, you'd need a guarantee that multiple updates to the scene do not get lumped together by blender and only cause a single invocation of the handler. This [...]

Comment: [...] is something I can see Blender doing for performance purposes (for example, maybe scene_update_post gets called at most every 10ms, and if there are multiple changes to the scene in a single 10ms interval, all of them together cause only one invocation of the handler). Of course, I don't know whether this is the case, but I'd have to find it documented or thoroughly test every single version of Blender to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem myself a while ago - the way i solved it was basically using a semaphore-like approach, where the handler would set a boolean value to true when it is invoked, and set it to false before it returns. Before setting the boolean, it would first check if it was already set, and if so, return without executing. I doubt that race conditions are a thing in Blender's python API, but hey, it works.

```
handler_running = False

    def handler():
        if handler_running:
            return
        handler_running = True
        # Do something
        handler_running = False
```